# Mysql Check date between two column and also check less date by one column

Tags: mysql

I have 2 column in my database

`start_date = 2016-07-28` **&** `end_date = 2016-07-29`

now i want to check a date between these dates and also smaller date in may database recored in `start_date` column.

Comment: can you please share what you done till now?

Comment: Do you have two questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for greater and less than condition (if you want to include these dates too just check for equality too like I do in the example).

For example if the date you want to check is '2016-07-28' you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE '2016-07-28' >= `start_date` AND '2016-07-28' <= `end_date`
```

If you want to find the smallest date that the `start_date` column has you can just use `MIN()` function:

```
SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM `your_table`
```